# how to get new coordinates with width, length and angle known?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, trigonometry

I have trapezoid with three coordinates known. So I need to create 4th coordinate with length, width and angles I am having. You can assume this problem with triangle as ADC from trapezoid. The model comes as differently expected . The Law of cosines gives the angle but it should be applied to local coordinates of the model. Right side I am showing with arrow pointed as wrong object which i am getting. Even if I rotate the object or flip it, the coordinates should not get wrong.

newWidth2 is AB. newLength is AD. Point C need to be created from A,D with angle D. Math.Pow is "to the power of" and 2 is it's square.(for who can't understand this notation).

Assume that I dont have coordinates of C. I know only A,D coordinates. I know length of AD, Width2 and Width1. I can get angle ADC from initial coordinates of C where coordinates of C will vary when I change Width2 of DC. So coordinates of C will be based on length of AD, angle D and so on. Finally what I need is coordinates of C if the entire object is rotated in any angle.

newWidth2 is AB.
newLength is AD.
Point C need to be created from A,D with angle A or angle D also.
Math.Pow is "to the power of" and 2 is it's square.(for who can't understand this notation).

```
//Initially I will have Coordinates for C but later I should remove them and create from the model width and heights. So I can't take input as C Coordinates of (X3,Y3) which I already have. 
            //distance formula
            newWidth2 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(CoordX3 - CoordX5, 2) + Math.Pow(CoordY3 - CoordY5, 2));
    //from the formula ->  b2 = a2 + c2 - 2acCos(B)
        diagangle = Math.Acos((Math.Pow(newWidth2, 2) - Math.Pow(newdiagonal, 2) - Math.Pow(newLength, 2)) / (-2 * (newdiagonal) * (newLength))   );
```

---

```
//I am getting this C coordinates as wrong.
     //for getting C (third coordinates)            
        xcoord3 = CoordX5 + (newWidth2 * Math.Cos(diagangle));
        ycoord3 = CoordY5 + (newWidth2 * Math.Sin(diagangle));
```

[image]

```
//sample values of one model
Width1   36
Width2   24
Length     88.0783
A
CoordX1 43.944
CoordY1 409.2514
B
CoordX2 46.9337
CoordY2 373.3758
C
CoordX3 133.7111
CoordY3 392.6488
D
CoordX4 131.718
CoordY4 416.5659
```

Comment: You have not specified clearly what values/parameters are given

Comment: values and parameters will be changing for each model. it need to be dynamic. I need the formula for third coordinates with local coordinates. please check now for 1 sample model. Your answer need to be equal with coordinates of C. I have the coordinates of C but they need to be generated only with ADC or their angles, widths and length.

Comment: I still don't understand. You've shown coordinates of 4 points. What are you going to do further?

Comment: My problem is, this is 3D model and I will be changing the width of CD so automatically the coordinates need to shift from point C to according to the width given. This need to be dynamic. Not from static point which is given in the beginning. This point should be generated from the length AD, angle A, angle D and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what exactly is known and what is to be found. I assume that you know coordinates of `A`, `B`, `C` and length `AB` = `width1` and `CD` = `width2` and need to find coordinates of `D`.

I think this problem is easier to solve if you see it as a vector problem rather than a trigonometry problem. If you look at vectors `BA` and `CD` you may see that they are collinear and `|BA|` = `width1` while `|CD|` = `width2`. It means that vector `CD` = `width2/width1 * BA`. Not you can trivially calculate the coordinates of `D` by:

1. Calculating vector `BA`
2. Calculating `CD` = `width2/width1 * BA`
3. Calculating `D` = `C + CD`

Comment: @MadhuKumar, do you have coordinate of `B`? If yes, just change `C` and `D` in my answer (and reverse the direction of the vector `CD` to `DC`). If no, how do you know the direction of the lines `AB` and `CD`?

Comment: @MadhuKumar, so if you know coordinates of `A`, `B` and `D` and also `width1` and `width2` why can't you use my answer just changing `C` and `D` as I suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: @MadhuKumar, what I'm trying to say is that if you know all that I listed in the previous question, you don't have to use the angle `ADC`. Not every solution has to go the route you want it to go. So my question is: what data you lack to use my solution instead of yours?

Comment: @MadhuKumar, I'm not sure how I can elaborate it further. If you already know coordinates of `A`, `B` and `D` and `width1` and `width2`, you may calculate coordinates of `C` as `Xc = Xd + width2/width1*(Xb - Xa)` (and the same goes for the `Y` coordinate)

Comment: Example with your data `Xc` = `131.718 + 24/36*(46.9337- 43.944)` ≈ `133.7`. `Yc` = `416.5659 + 24/36*(373.3758 -  409.2514)` ≈ `392.6`

Comment: @MadhuKumar, I expect it to work in any case. Could you provide some numerical example when this doesn't work?

Comment: is it possible without considering Width1 in this calculation?

Comment: @MadhuKumar, well, no you need both `Width1` and `Width2`. However the important question is what data do you know about the trapezoid that makes it fully defined? It might be easier to calculate `Width1` from that data than to use another method to calculate position of the last point.

Comment: problem arises when i change Width1 height. I will be changing both Width1 and Width2 after the model is created. So according to that my calculations should work. That is the reason I am not mixing Width1 with Width2 in the question.

Comment: @MadhuKumar, sorry I don't understand your problem from this description. You have different operations with different algorithms to calculate new points positions. Why existence of an operation to change `width1` should affect the algorithm to be used for rotation?

Comment: yes, you can assume that my object rotates. Initially after creating my object if I change the Width1 height it should not effect Width2 height. Same with Wdth1 as well.

Comment: @MadhuKumar, Sorry but I just don't understand the meaning of the text in your comments (and how they are relevant to my answer and my commntes) so I can't help you further.

Comment: could you please check for these values:Width1 =36, Width2= 32.6946, Length= 39.6648, X1 =10.502, Y1= 369.5244, X2   =  46.502, 
Y2   =     369.5244 ,
X3  =      43.1966,
Y3   =     409.1891,  X4 =10.502, Y4= 406.4646. There is slight variation. Y2 is getiing 372.5139 instead of approx 369.5244. Y3 is getting 406.4646 instead of 409.1891. I am giving X2,Y2 & X3,Y3 values for your reference.

Comment: @MadhuKumar, sorry but how am I supposed to verify anything? To do that I at least need to have a fully-defined trapezoid and a triplet `Width1`, `Width2`, `Length` does not fully define an arbitrary trapezoid.

Comment: Distance between A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2) is Width1. AD is length. CD is Width2. I gave you all the values know. I am getting wrong output if the angle ADC is more than 90 degrees. In this case it is 95 degrees.